# How can i format visual studio code to add an indented space between curly brackets in CSS when i hit enter?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

When I open the curly brackets in CSS and hit enter, it just jumps to the next line like this:

```
body {
}
```

It doesn't add a new line with an indentation like it used to, I tried looking through the setting and trying everything but couldn't get a result.
I want it to look like this when I press Enter:

```
body {
    
}
```

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff yes tested right now, yes actually "prettier" does that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who is facing this problem in VSCode. This feature is not related to any extension, not Prettier or any other extension. What you have to do to fix this bug is:

1. **Go to the *settings***
2. **Search for *Folding Strategy* and choose the *Auto* option**
3. **Then enable Folding**

It adds that indentation in both HTML and CSS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a VSCode plugin called "Prettier".

It can be downloaded in the "Extensions" section of VSCode,
or downloaded from this link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: I already have Prettier but still the same

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the following:**

1. Check if you have set your default formatter to prettier
2. You can check the box to Format On Save or ;
3. Autosave: There are are currently 4 options available -:

**a) off**

**b) afterDelay**

**c) onFocusChange**

**d) onWindowChange**

Comment: It didn't work and Prettier formats the code when you save it and not while you're writing it. The problem is in the VSCode settings because that function comes with VSCode and not with Prettier or any other extension